# Split by comma if that comma is not located between two double quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking to split such string by comma :

```
 field1:"value1", field2:"value2", field3:"value3,value4"
```

into a `string[]` that would look like:

```
0     field1:"value1"
1     field2:"value2"
2     field3:"value3,value4"
```

I am trying to do that with `Regex.Split` but can't seem to work out the regular expression.

Comment: Can't you just split on `",` in that case?

Comment: @webnoob this would remove the trailing `"` too, just to bare in mind.

Comment: @LukeHennerley - If you know it's going to be missing it's not much to put it back if it's required.

Comment: @webnoob indeed it is, just making sure people know before posting anything to do it this way.

Comment: Not sure you can do this with a regex.  But it wouldn't be too hard to just scan the string.  Start at the beginning and look for commas.  Keep track of whether or not you're currently in a quoted string.

Comment: @LukeHennerley - Good point. +1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'll be much easier to do this with `Matches` than with `Split`, for example

```
string[] asYouWanted = Regex.Matches(input, @"[A-Za-z0-9]+:"".*?""")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

although if there is *any* chance of your values (or fields!) containing escaped quotes (or anything similarly tricky), then you might be better off with a proper CSV parser.

---

If you *do* have escaped quotes in your values, I think the following regex *the* work - give it a test:

```
@"field3:""value3\\"",value4""", @"[A-Za-z0-9]+:"".*?(?<=(?<!\\)(\\\\)*)"""
```

The added `(?<=(?<!\\)(\\\\)*)` is supposed to make sure that the `"` it stops matching on is preceeded by only an even number of slashes, as an odd number of slashes means it is escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but this should be Ok:

```
string[] parts = string.Split(new string[] { ",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

remember to add the " back on the end if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] arr = str.Split(new string[] {"\","}}, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(str => str + "\"").ToArray();
```

Split by `\,` as webnoob mentioned and then suffix with the trailing `"` using a select, then cast to an array.

Comment: Seems like Split can't take string[] as parameter

Comment: And how would one intelligently not append " to the last item in Linq ?

Comment: @Franklin see my edit, I think I was missing the `stringsplitoptions` parameter. I don't understand what you mean by the second comment?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// (\w.+?):"(\w.+?)"        
//         
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w.+?)»        
//    Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»        
//    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+?»        
//       Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»        
// Match the characters “:"” literally «:"»        
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\w.+?)»        
//    Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»        
//    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+?»        
//       Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»        
// Match the character “"” literally «"»        


try {        
    Regex regObj = new Regex(@"(\w.+?):""(\w.+?)""");        
    Match matchResults = regObj.Match(sourceString);        
    string[] arr = new string[match.Captures.Count];        
    int i = 0;        
    while (matchResults.Success) {        
        arr[i] = matchResults.Value;        
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();        
        i++;        
    }         
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {        
    // Syntax error in the regular expression        
}
```

Comment: have you copied RegexBodies explanation and pasted it here?

Comment: I knew I know that slang :D

Answer (score 0):

The easiest inbuilt way is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546818/344822). I checed it . It is working fine. It splits `"Hai,\"Hello,World\""` into `{"Hai","Hello,World"}`