# how to split comma with double quotes in c#?

Tags: c#, csv

```
string strExample = 
"\"10553210\",\"na\",\"398,633,000\",\"20130709\",\"20130502\",\"20120724\",";
```

how to split above string with `","`

I need an answer like

```
string[] arrExample = YourFunc(strExample);       
arrExample[0] == "10553210";       
arrExample[1] == "na";
arrExample[2] == "398,633,000";
...
```

with split option.

thanks in advance

Comment: You know you can't build a string as a list of comma-separated values, right? What does your *actual* string look like?

Comment: That isn't a string in your example.

Comment: Most of the answers given here are correct, still you are in search

Comment: this is the answer i got finally   strFiledata.Split(new string[]{"\",\""},StringSplitOptions.None);

Comment: @janakiakula, please don't answer your own question with a comment. Several of the answers here are the same as your comment. Please show the courtesy of upvoting the answers you found useful. Then mark the earliest one that that was correct as the answer. Otherwise, next time, nobody will want to answer your questions and your posts will be largely useless to later visitors.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an easy way,

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

IList<string> arrExample;
using(var csvParser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(strExample))
{
    fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
}
```

Comment: a very nice inbuilt solution. You saved me from unneccessary search and regex.

Answer (score 4):

You may split not by comma `","` but by whole string `"\",\""`.
Do not forget to `Trim` leading and trailing quotations `"`:

```
 String strExample =
   "\"10553210\",\"na\",\"398,633,000\",\"20130709\",\"20130502\",\"20120724\"";

 string[] arrExample = St.Trim('"').Split(new String[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split on "," , The first and last entry you have to clean the " in the last and first entry:

```
string[] arr = strExample .Split(new string[] { "\",\"" },
               StringSplitOptions.None);

//remove the extra quotes from the last and the first entry
arr[0] = arr[0].SubString(1,arr[0].Length - 1);
int last = arr.Length - 1;
arr[last] = arr[last].SubString(0,arr[last].Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arrExample = strExample.Split(",");
```

would do it, but your code won't compile. I assume you meant:

```
string strExample = "10553210,na,398,633,000,20130709,20130502,20120724";
```

If this isn't what you meant, please correct the question.

Comment: Thanks for answer
I need this 
string[] arrExample = strExample.Split(new string[]{"\",\""}

Comment: Then I think @peer's answer might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant this:

```
string strExample = "\"10553210\",\"na\",\"398,633,000\",\"20130709\",\"20130502\",\"20120724\"";
```

`Split` then `Select` the substring:

```
string[] parts = strExample.Split(',').Select(x => x.Substring(1, x.Length - 2)).ToArray();
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

```
strExample.Split(',');
```

You need to escape the double quotes if they're meant to be contained in your example string.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example from Jodrell

```
  private string[] SplitFields(string csvValue)
  {
     //if there aren't quotes, use the faster function
     if (!csvValue.Contains('\"') && !csvValue.Contains('\''))
     {
        return csvValue.Trim(',').Split(',');
     }
     else
     {
        //there are quotes, use this built in text parser
        using(var csvParser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(new StringReader(csvValue.Trim(','))))
        {
           csvParser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
           csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
           return csvParser.ReadFields();
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitCSV(string strInput)
    {
        string[] str = strInput.Split(',');
        if (str == null)
            yield return null;

        StringBuilder quoteS = null;
        foreach (string s in str)
        {
            if (s.StartsWith("\""))
            {
                if (s.EndsWith("\""))
                {
                    yield return s;
                }
                quoteS = new StringBuilder(s);
                continue;
            }

            if (quoteS != null)
            {
                quoteS.Append($",{s}");
                if (s.EndsWith("\""))
                {
                    string s1 = quoteS.ToString();
                    quoteS = null;
                    yield return s1;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }



            yield return s;
        }
    }
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "111,222,\"33,44,55\",666,\"77,88\",\"99\"";
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        var sp = SplitCSV(s);

        foreach (string s1 in sp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s1);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

you can do that by doing this ..

```
string stringname= "10553210,na,398,633,000,20130709,20130502,20120724";
 List<String> asd = stringname.Split(',');
```

or if you wanr array then

```
array[] asd = stringname.Split(',').ToArray;
```